# Woocommerce how to get custom field value from function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im tring to get custom field value via functions.php using this code:

```
function discount_base_quantity(){
    global $woocommerce;
    global $post;

    $product  = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
        $product_id = wc_get_product($value['data']->get_id());
    $field = get_post_meta($product_id,'option_a');
    echo $field; }}
```

But it didnt work. what am i missing? is there another way to do that?

Comment: yes this is correct

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. actualy i didnt pass the product id in get_post_meta function. so this code is work for me:

```
        function discount_base_quantity(){
        global $woocommerce;

        $product  = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
                $id = $value['product_id'];
                //echo $product_id;
                $field = get_post_meta($id,'option_a', true);
                echo $field;
}
    }
```